# Rails/General HTML: How to submit content from two forms?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, dom, html5-canvas

Here is my problem: I have a view with two forms, a CartItem form and a WishList form. The CartItem form has a few integers in it, as well as a `file_field` for the user's desired logo to attach.

A `wish_item` is the same thing as a `cart_item` in the database.

When submitted, javascript fills in the hidden `wish_item` fields with the data from the `cart_item` form.

See this code for a more clear idea of what I mean:

```
$('#add-to-wish-list').click(function(){
  $('#wish_item_color_id').val($('#cart_item_color_id').val());
  $('#wish_item_quantity').val($('#cart_item_quantity').val());
});
```

My problem is sending the image through the `wish_item` form.

The file field is a part of the `cart_item` form, and I don't know how to send that field with the `wish_item` form.

Sorry that the question is sort of vague, but I'm not allowed to post the source code directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fields_for to pass parameters to a form that is different to the rest of the form

```
<%= form_for @person, url: {action: "create"} do |person_form| %>
  <%= person_form.text_field :name %>
  <%= fields_for @person.contact_detail do |contact_details_form| %>
    <%= contact_details_form.text_field :phone_number %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```